# How to grant SELECT access for Drupal user to all CiviCRM Tables

Tags: drupal, civicrm.settings.php

I have 2 databases for Drupal and CiviCRM. How can I grant SELECT access for Drupal user to all CiviCRM tables? I am using AWS RDS Databases. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to perform two operations for this

1. Give Drupal mysql user to access CiviCRM database.
2. Add CiviCRM tables in Drupal's settings.php i.e Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> CMS Database Integration. Copy the content from  'Views integration settings' section to settings.php. Clear Drupal cache.

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep! How can I copy the content from 'Views Integration Settings' section to settings.php? Thanks!

Comment: Copy from UI and paste it at the end of the file.

Comment: I don't know how to give access drupal mysql user to access CiviCRM database. Because I am using aws rds? Do you know how to? Please help. Thanks so much!

Comment: You can raise a support ticket to aws for granting access or use cpanel/whm if you have access to it.